# How to use exception to make the code runs through every thing listed?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I have two directories with identical folder tree structure and file names. These are the data of current week and last week. I am combining (append the new data to the old ones) each pair of them (name to name) into and save it under another directory with the original file tree structure.

How do I throw exception/use try-catch if I want it to go through (skip if not exist) all files listed in the directory?

Or is there any mistake I am making?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Merge {
    public static void  main(String[] args) {
        List<String> fileListA = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (args.length != 3) {
            System.out.println("Usage: Merge -DirA -DirB -OutputDir");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Path:" + args[0]);
            // Read all text file from the specified path
            fileListA = getInputFileNames(args[0], "txt");

            int count = 0;
            for (String str : fileListA){
                String data;
                // Path of files form DirA and DirB
                String filePathA = str;
                System.out.println("PathA:" + filePathA);
                String filePathB = str.replace(args[0], args[1]);
                System.out.println("PathB:" + filePathB);
                // Buffer for reading fileA and fileB
                BufferedReader brA = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePathA));
                BufferedReader brB = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePathB));
                // Create fileOut object
                File fileOut = new File(str.replace(args[0], args[2]));
                System.out.println("PathOut:" + str.replace(args[0], args[2]));
                // Create fileOut if doesn't exist
                if (!fileOut.exists()) {
                    fileOut.createNewFile();
                }
                // Buffer for writing fileOut
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileOut.getAbsoluteFile()));
                // Read through fileA and fileB, append each line to fileOut
                while ((data = brA.readLine()) != null) {
                    bw.write(data);
                    bw.newLine();
                }
                brA.close();
                while ((data = brB.readLine()) != null) {
                    bw.write(data);
                    bw.newLine();
                }
                brB.close();
                bw.close();
                count++;
            }

            System.out.println("Files done"+ count);
        }

    }

    public static List<String> getInputFileNames(String sDir, String ext){
        // Get all file names from a given path, recursively go into each sub-directory as well

        //System.getProperty("file.separator");
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        File [] files = new File(sDir).listFiles();
        for (File file : files){
            if (file.isFile()){
                String fName = file.getAbsolutePath();
                if (fName.substring(fName.lastIndexOf(".")+1).equalsIgnoreCase(ext)){
                    results.add(fName);
                }               
            } else if (file.isDirectory()){
                List<String> subResults = getInputFileNames(file.getPath(), ext); 
                if (!subResults.isEmpty()){
                    results.addAll(subResults);
                }
            } else {
                // Not a file or directory
            }
        }
        return results;
    }

}
```